# Foreign key always is null

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make tables `ItemGroupe` and `Item`.  I want `ItemGroupe_ID` as foreign Key in `Itam` table. I have by this foreign key always the value null. Can anyone provide sample code to do this?

Item_Group table:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ITEM_GROUP = "CREATE TABLE " + RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.TABLE_NAMES[0] + " (" +
            RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMN_NAME_GROUP_ITEM[1] + " TEXT)";
```

Item table:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE " + RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.TABLE_NAMES[1] + "(" +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[0] + " TEXT," +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[1] + " TEXT," +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[2] + " TEXT," +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[3] + " TEXT," +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[4] + " INTEGER," +
        " FOREIGN KEY ("+RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[4]+") REFERENCES " +
        RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.TABLE_NAMES[0] + "("+RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry._ID+"));";
```

OnCreate:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM_GROUP);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM);
        }
```

Add Item_Group:

```
public boolean addOne(ItemGroup itemGroup) {

    openWD();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMN_NAME_GROUP_ITEM[1], itemGroup.getItemGroup_Name());

    long insert = db.insert(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.TABLE_NAMES[0], null, cv);
    return insert != -1;
}
```

Add item:

```
public boolean addOne(Item item) {

    openWD();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[0], item.getItem_name());
    cv.put(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[1], item.getItem_SKU());
    cv.put(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[2], item.getItem_brand());
    cv.put(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[3], item.getItem_color());

    long insert = db.insert(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.TABLE_NAMES[1], null, cv);
    return insert != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are under the impression that SQLite will generate the foreign key values automatically.

That is you do not provide the value of the respective column when inserting an Item. More specifically you do not have a `cv.put(cv.put(RawColumnContract.RawColumnEntry.COLUMNS_NAME_ITEM[4], ....;`.

You need to set the relevant value (i.e. the `....` above) to the respective ItemGroupe parent.